# How to prove that a function defined recursively really exist?

Tags: real-analysis, induction, recursion

I have an example of an inductively defined set and a function on that set. But I am wondering if one should do more work to really show that the function exist? The set is:

The smallest set that contains $3$ and $4$, and is such that if $x$ is an element of the set and $x$ is an odd number, then $2x-1$ is an element of the set, and also if $x$ is an element of the set and $x$ is an even number then $x+4$ is an element of that set.

I define the function $f$ like this $f(3)=1,f(4)=2$. If $x$ is odd than $f(2x-1)=2f(x)$, if $x$ is even than $f(x+4)=f(x)+2$.

Is there a way to show that the set we are working with and the function we define really are well-defined? Intuitively they will be well-defined since we define it by elements we have already defined, and we only define it on elements that are in our set, but this doesn't seem enough?

Comment: See the Axiom of Infinity and the Axiom schema of replacement.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your set is the union of all integers of the form $2^m + 1$ for integer $m \geq 1$, and all integers of the form $4m$ for $m \geq 1$.  This might be a more concrete definition to work with.

Comment: You may want to read up on the *recursion theorem*.

Comment: I am not sure that you are dealing with a function over that set, let alone that you would need to show that that function is well-defined. Aren't you just dealing with a set, and having to show that that set is well-defined?

Comment: @Bram28 The function is the function $f$.

Comment: @Michael Seifert I chose it as an example, I'd like something that would also work for similar examples, but then we may not find explicit formulas for the elements. Ao I would like something a bit general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we have the following property on a set $A$:

- $\{3, 4\} \subseteq A$, and
- for all $x \in A,x$ is odd $\implies 2x - 1 \in A$, and
- for all $x \in A,x$ is even $\implies x + 4 \in A$

Note that there is at least one set with this property, $\Bbb N$.
Also note that if $\mathscr A$ is a collection of sets all satisfying the property, then the intersection $$\bigcap_{A \in \mathscr A}A := \{x \mid \forall A \in \mathscr A, x \in A\}$$
is also a set satisfying the property.

But we can define such an $\mathscr A$ by $$\mathscr A := \{A \subseteq \Bbb N\mid A \text{ satisfies the property}\}$$
$\mathscr A$ at least has $\Bbb N$ as a member, so the intersection of $\mathscr A$ is not empty.

If $B$ is any set having the property, then $B \cap \bigcap_{A \in \mathscr A}A \subseteq \Bbb N$ and also has the property. Thus $B \cap \bigcap_{A \in \mathscr A}A \in \mathscr A$, which means $$\bigcap_{A \in \mathscr A}A\subseteq B \cap \bigcap_{A \in \mathscr A}A$$
which can only be if $\bigcap_{A \in \mathscr A}A \subseteq B$.

Therefore $\bigcap_{A \in \mathscr A}A$ is a subset of every set with the property, which makes it the smallest such set.

---

This proof works more generally. If you have some property on sets that is preserved under intersection (even intersections of any collection of sets with the property), and there is at least one set with the property, this proof shows that there must be a smallest set with the property. This is not induction. It just follows from the basic behavior of sets. But it can be used to show that any well-formed inductive definition of a set does indeed fully define the set.

And since functions can be expressed as subsets of the product of the domain and codomain, it also can be used to prove inductive definition of a function is valid.

---

[Added] One way to apply this to functions is to consider subsets $S$ of $\Bbb N \times \Bbb N$ with the property (for your example)

- $\{(3,1), (4, 2)\} \subseteq S$, and
- if $(x, y) \in S$ and $x$ is odd, then $(2x-1, 2y) \in S$, and
- if $(x,y) \in S$ and $x$ is even, then $(x + 4, x+2) \in S$.

Call this property $P(S)$. Obviously $P(\Bbb N \times \Bbb N)$ holds, and for any collection $\mathscr A$ of sets, if for all $A \in \mathscr A, P(A)$ holds, then $P(\bigcap \mathscr A)$ also holds. Thus as above, there is a smallest subset $f$ of $\Bbb N \times \Bbb N$ for which it holds.

Note that $P$ was applied to general subsets of $\Bbb N \times \Bbb N$, not just to *functions*. If we had tried to limit $P$ to functions from the start, then no, we do not have a handy top function that satisfies the condition, so we could not claim that $\{A \in \Bbb N^2\mid P(A)\}$ is not empty. In fact, $f$ would be the maximum set in that collection, not the the minimum. To avoid these issues, I allow non-functional sets.

But now you have to show from the properties that $\text{Dom}(f) := \{x \mid \exists y, (x,y) \in f\}$ is the inductively defined set above, and that $f$ is a function. I.e., if $(x,y), (x,z) \in f$ then $y = z$. (For this, you can assume $y \ne z$, then use that to show that either $y$ or $z$ could be discarded without violating $P$, meaning if $f$ contained both it would not be the smallest, contrary to its definition.)

Comment: Thank you. I have one question regarding your last sentence, if I am going to use this to show that the function is well-defined, do I then need that we have atleast one bigger function has this property? Is that easy to see in our case for our $f$?

Comment: Not a bigger function - that is generally not possible. But a bigger set is possible. I've added an outline of the approach to the bottom of my post. There are also other ways to showing inductive definition is justified. Such as buiding $f$ as the union of an increasing sequence of smaller subsets of $\Bbb N \times \Bbb N$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I hope I can trouble you for one last question. When we at the last step is supposed to show that the domain is the inductively defined set, can we use structural induction, or would you do it another way?

Comment: A simpler way would be to show that $\text{Dom}(f)$ satisfies the properties defining the set, and therefore must contain that smallest set (call it $\tilde A$). But then note that $f|_{\tilde A}$ satisfies the ocndition $P$ defining $f$ despite being a subset of $f$. Since $f$ is the smallest such set, $f|_{\tilde A} = f$ and therefore $\text{Dom}(f) = \tilde A$. Alternatively, unless you need this characterization of $\text{Dom}(f)$ for some purpose, you could simply not bother to define $\tilde A$ as anything other than $\text{Dom}(f)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this was very useful.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: This is exactly the same as the answer of Paul Sinclair, but shorter and with less notation.

---

We can actually do something simpler.  Let's let $P$ be the property that you want your set to have  (it should contain 3 and 4, and so  on as you said).

1. If $\mathcal F$ is any nonempty family of sets, and if every set in $\mathcal F$ has property $P$, then $\bigcap\mathcal F$, the intersection of the sets in $\mathcal F$, also has property $P$.  (You can prove this.)

   The definition of $\bigcap\mathcal F$ is: A number $n$ is in $\bigcap\mathcal F$ if and only if $n$ is in every one of the sets in $\mathcal F$.
2. Let $\mathcal G$ be the family of *all* the sets with property $P$.  This family is nonempty because, for example, $\Bbb Z\in \mathcal G$.  (The set of all integers obviously has property $P$.)
3. Then let $S = \bigcap\mathcal G$.  By (1), set $S$ has property $P$.  And it is the smallest set with property $P$, because if $T$ is any set with property $P$, then $S\subset T$.  (You can show this too.)

Comment: Does this method work to show that the function is well-defined?

Comment: Your function is not well-defined because none of the rules you gave defines $f(7)$.

Comment: But 7 is not in the set we define at the start either, so it doesn't need to be defined.

Comment: It's not clear what you think the domain of the function is.

Comment: The domain is the set defined earlier in the post.